# How to first cancel a unique work then upon the cancellation enqueue a NOT unique work?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I have an enqueued unique work `work1` under the name `WORK1_NAME`.
I want to cancel it and upon the cancellation (right after `work1` gets completely cancelled), enqueue a NOT unique work `work2`.
So, I want something like the following:

```
val work2 = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder.build()
val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
workManager.
  .beginWith(workManager.cancelUniqueWork(WORK1_NAME))
  .then(work2)
  .enqueue()
```

but `workManager.cancelUniqueWork()` returns an `Operation`, which cannot be passed to `workManager.beginWith()`.

My scenario is:

- when the `work2` gets started, the `work1` must be cancelled right before;
- when the `work1` gets started, it doesn't affect the `work2`.

Actually, I could implement a worker that do `workManager.cancelUniqueWork(WORK1_NAME)` synchronously, but it does not seem idiomatic.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try observing the state of the Work via LiveData and when it is finished - start the new one.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/managing-work#observing

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't fit my needs, since I want it to be as a some kind of _transaction_. So I mean even though the user shut down the app, I want the work being continued anyway, but with `LiveData` I have to maintain this manually.